# EmojiCompat for Huawei devices

Tags: android, fonts, emoji, huawei-mobile-services, google-fonts

I would like to support emojis for Huawei devices in my app. For all other vendors I use code like this to init EmojiCompat:

```
 val fontRequest = FontRequest(
            "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
            "com.google.android.gms",
            "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
            R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs
        )
        val config = FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(context, fontRequest)
        EmojiCompat.init(config)
```

But for Huawei devices, for they do not have access to google resources (my guess), it does not work, and EmojiCompat doesn't get initialized. I know that `BundledEmojiCompatConfig` could be used, but I would prefer always to fetch the newest font.

Is there any alternative to Google's providerAuthority/Package for Huawei devices?

Comment: I was searching for HMS AppConnect and HMS Core documentation for anything on `Font` and `FontRequest`, seem they don't have any service.You should roll with bundling.

Comment: That's unlucky. I guess that Huawei's ecosystem is not there yet. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What specific error did you get? And on which device model? I just tested this sample https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/EmojiCompat on a Huawei Mate 30 Pro ( without Google services ) and it's working

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `BundledEmojiCompatConfig` for devices having no access to `GMS`.

For example:

1. Add dependency:

```
def emojiCompatVersion = "1.0.0-rc01"

implementation 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views:$emojiCompatVersion'
implementation 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-bundled:$emojiCompatVersion'
```

2. Helper Class to Initialize EmojiCompat

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import androidx.emoji2.bundled.BundledEmojiCompatConfig
import androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompat
import androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompat.LOAD_STRATEGY_MANUAL

object EmojiCompatHandler {

    fun initializeEmojiCompat(appContext: Context) {
        val config = BundledEmojiCompatConfig(appContext)
            .setReplaceAll(true)
            .setMetadataLoadStrategy(LOAD_STRATEGY_MANUAL)
            .registerInitCallback(object : EmojiCompat.InitCallback() {
                override fun onInitialized() {
                    logDebug("EmojiCompat Initialized Successfully")
                }

                override fun onFailed(throwable: Throwable?) {
                    logDebug("EmojiCompat Failed to Load: ${throwable?.message}")
                }
            })

        EmojiCompat.init(config)
    }
}
```

3. Initialize `EmojiCompat` as early as possible (can be pretty slow from what I've observed),
   either via `Application#onCreate()` or `App Startup`
   (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup)

Answer (score 0):

EmojiCompat is part of Android and is not exclusive to Google Mobile Services. I tested the below demo app that has the same code snippet as yours, and it works fine on my Huawei Mate 30 Pro.

[Github link.](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/EmojiCompat)

Comment: And what about "You need the beta version of Google Play Services to use this feature" part? Not all Huawei devices, especially not the new ones, come with any Google related packages

Comment: Can you provide more information on this issue? I did not receive this message when I was tested EmojiCompat. It shouldn't give any Google-related errors at all, as it is an Android component.